# IPv6 Apple updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

With the recent announcements by Apple regarding Supporting IPv6-only Networks. I have few queries:

1) I have code which uses NSURLConnection all over the place and I think it comes under CFNetwork APIs.

Do I need to update my code to NSURLSession mandatorily as mentioned on their website: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a

2) IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses:

What does IPv4 specific APIs are there ? I dont see good documentation on Apple website about this. If anyone has any insights on this and can help me out it would be really helpful.

Comment: 1- Very probably, yes. 2- As long as you don't use hardcoded IPv4 values such as "123.456.789.2" and as long as none of your APIs expects such an hardcoded string, you're ok.

Comment: Thanks Eric. So it means we have to move to NSURLSession ?

Comment: I don't know when NSURLConnection will be hard-deprecated (for now it's only soft-deprecated) but it would be good anyway to not wait too much to port your codebase to NSURLSession, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

1. NSURLConnection is fine (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW21)
2. Apple lets you use BSD sockets directly, and it would be possible to implement code based on that which doesn't cope with IPv6. Hardcoded IPv4 addresses "123.123.123.123" won't resolve over IPv6, you should always be looking up IP addresses "www.stackoverflow.com"

In fact, it's probably a good idea to read the whole of the doc I linked to above. Amongst other things, it includes details of how to test IPv6 compatibility by sharing your regular internet connection using a El Capitan Mac as an simulated IPv6 access point.

Comment: But NSURLConnection has deprected lots of methods going ios 9 and above. I feel they dont want us to use that anymore. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

Comment: Well, NSURLConnection may or may not be a good choice of API in general terms (I don't feel I'm well informed enough on it to comment), but in terms of IPv6 support it's right there in the 'recommended' category in Figure 10-5 of the UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition doc.